# How to find closest matching items for a given query?

Tags: probability, searching

Given 3 items `i` with probability values: `p` of belonging to 3 classes `c` as:

```
i1 = c1(p=1),c2(p=0),c3(p=1)

i2 = c1(p=1),c2(p=0.6),c3(p=0)

i3 = c1(p=0.9),c2(p=0.6),c3(p=0.1)
```

How to calculate each products probability score match to below query ?:

```
q = c1(p=1),c2(p=1),c3(p=0)
```

I am thinking to solve it by by computing one value for each `i` that could be compared with value produced by the query as:

```
val i1 = (1 * 100) + (0 * 1000) +  (0 * 10000)
val i2 = (1 * 100) + (0.6 * 1000) +  (0 * 10000)
val i3 = (0.9 * 100) + (0.6 * 1000) +  (0.1 * 10000)     

val q = (1 * 100) + (1 * 1000) +  (0 * 10000)
```

with results as:

```
i1: Int = 100
i2: Double = 700.0
i3: Double = 1690.0
q: Int = 1100
```

and then compare the values, am I on a right track ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thx, @JoséCarlosSantos, I will learn how to use it.